# Moving checkboxes back and forth between parent and modal

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, append

I have a list of country checkboxes on the parent screen. I also provide a modal (div) which contains those same countries and provides the User with more country options.

Any checkbox changes made in the parent listbox need to carry over to the modal, and any changes made in the modal must be reflected back in the parent listbox when the modal is closed.

In a drastically cut-down fiddle you can see that my jquery doesn't append the checkboxes to the modal (...and I'll probably need help getting them back to the parent too!) .  I have searched previous posts but nothing works so far. Can anyone help?

https://jsfiddle.net/a4Ld3e0t/

```js
$('#openCountryRegionModal').click(function() {
  var targetBox = $(this).prop("checked") ? '#ModalContainerID' : '.CountryRHWrapperClass';
  $('.myWorldCountries').appendTo($(targetBox));
});
```

```css
#ModalCountryButtonID {
  color: red;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
/* Modal code  */

#ModalContainerID {
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: calc(8vw);
  margin-right: calc(8vw);
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
.close {
  color: orange;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 5px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Store Countries -->
<div class=CountryRHWrapperClass>
  <label class="myWorldCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Spain" />Spain</label>
  <label class="myWorldCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label class="myWorldCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Belgium" />Belgium</label>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<!-- Create Link button to open modal ------------------------------------>
<div class="ModalButtonRegionCountryDivClass">
  <a href="#openCountryRegionModal" id="ModalCountryButtonID">Open modal</a>
</div>
<!-- Trigger modal ---------------------------------->
<div id="openCountryRegionModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <!-- Append countries to modal here ------------------------>
    <div id="ModalContainerID" class="ModalContainerClass"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a javascript function and add some id's and attach a method to each checkbox to get this functionality.
There are several ways you can use the methods of your checkbox and jQuery is certainly not necessary for this either as native javascript would work easily.

Here is one simple version:

Javascript:

```
function checkMyBox(id, modal) {
    if(typeof modal === "undefined") {
        if($('#' + id).is(":checked")) {
            $('#modal_' + id).prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('#modal_' + id).prop('checked', false);
        }
    } else {
        if($('#modal_' + id).is(":checked")) {
            $('#' + id).prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('#' + id).prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
}
```

Your body checkboxes will look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" onchange="checkMyBox(this.id);" /> Spain
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" onchange="checkMyBox(this.id);" /> Austria
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" onchange="checkMyBox(this.id);" /> Belgium
```

Your modal checkboxes will look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="modal_check1" onchange="checkMyBox('check1', 1);" /> Spain
<input type="checkbox" id="modal_check2" onchange="checkMyBox('check2', 1);" /> Austria
<input type="checkbox" id="modal_check3" onchange="checkMyBox('check3', 1);" /> Belgium
```

**Alternative method using element name arrays:**
You can also use name arrays. Here is an example using each name just twice but you could have it in as many places in the DOM as you needed.  BTW, this assumes your modal is a div in the body.

Javascript:

```
function checkMyBox2(name, checked) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByName(name);
    if (elems[i].type == "checkbox") {
        if(checked==true) {
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].checked = true;
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main body elements:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" onchange="checkMyBox2(this.name, this.checked);" /> Spain<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check2[]" onchange="checkMyBox2(this.name, this.checked);" /> Austria<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check3[]" onchange="checkMyBox2(this.name, this.checked);" /> Belgium
```

Modal elements:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" onchange="checkMyBox2(this.name, this.checked);" /> Spain<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check2[]" onchange="checkMyBox2(this.name, this.checked);" /> Austria<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check3[]" onchange="checkMyBox2(this.name, this.checked);" /> Belgium
```

Comment: Many thanks for this @Chris O.  Just to be clear, are you saying that I need one set of checkboxes for the parent and another set for the modal?  I've got 160 countries to deal with, and was obviously hoping I could use just one set for both parent and modal.  Is there no alternative way?

Comment: @Silverburch I added an alternate method using element name arrays. That should save you some naming. In fact you could put the checkboxes in an separate file and include it once in the body where needed and once in the modal and only have to write and edit it in one location (thats a server side script of your choice of course).